# How to count API clients using application insights, Web API .NET

Tags: .net, logging, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

I have created Web API service which is connected to the Azure Application Insights and also use `OpenTelemetry` to send data there.
I would like to count the number of users which use my API. Whenever I open API page (swagger) even on the multiple PC's, the counter under `Users` tab in the Application Insights, shows one user. What can I do, to show the correct `Users` number? I heard that maybe session id is missing, but I specified it in the `OpenTelemetry` by setting the tag `session.id` to `Guid.NewGuid();`.
If someone knows how to do it, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have set for `OpenTelemetry`.

Comment: What is the versionbof your webapp?

Comment: I think I found what was the issue. I had to create TelemetryInitialize where I set User.Id and Session.Id. After that I injected it as a Singleton and registered AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();. After that, number of users/sessions increased but still doesn't work well. I get to many users/sessions because OpenTelemetry and HealthChecks frequently send data to Azure. So the question is now, how to achieve the same without DI?

Comment: You can use Javascript sdk.Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-sdk?tabs=javascriptwebsdkloaderscript) for more details

Comment: This is web api, without js/html/css. Pure C#.

Comment: You can add the script in the `.cshtml` file

Comment: What is the version of your app?

Comment: Don't know how to check that, but nevertheless I don't have any views. It's simple api with swagger. The problem is whether I inject Initializer method, the method is being called every ~10s. So I'm looking for the different soluton

Comment: Open `.csproj` file and check the version.

Comment: Are you using `.net framework` or `.net core` ?

Comment: I use .net core 7.0

Comment: From your new question,it is clear that your issue is resolved.Are you still looking for the solution?

Comment: This one can be resolved

Comment: @Striker It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.